# How can I reduce 3 band rasters to 1 band and then create tiles of a different size with gdal?

Tags: gdal

I currently have over 3000 3 Band GeoTIFFs each with a size of 2000 x 2000 px with a resolution of 0,5m per pixel. I would like to reduce the 3 bands to 1 band and then increase the spatial extents/size of the images so that I only have to work with a maximum of 500

I am aware the a gdalbuildvrt will play a part in managing the process, but I am unsure how to reduce the bands from 3 to 1 and then create the tiles.

I have QGIS, ArcGIS and FME but would like to see if this is possible with gdal alone.

Comment: How do you want to reduce 3 bands to 1? Just take the first band? Take the average? Take some mixture of the three?

Comment: And by "increase the size of the images" do you mean to mosaic them in some way? So you might have fewer images but they could be 6000x6000 (and at the same 0.5m resolution)? Do the images tile perfectly? Are the images named such that identifying 3x3 groups to mosaic (giving a total of about 333 images) is not too difficult?

Comment: Or would you prefer to 255 color single band images with color palette from RGB originals?

Comment: I would like to increase the spatial extent of the images - so in some way mosaic by a factor of 1:8 or 1:16. A 255 single band with color palette sound great.

Comment: You mean bigger pixels? 500x500 with 2 m pixel size instead of 2000x2000 with 0.5 m pixels? Pixel size can be changed with gdal_translate or gdalwarp, for color palette use https://gdal.org/programs/rgb2pct.html.

Comment: I dont want to loose any ground resolution, but would like to increase the image size from 2000 x 2000 to maybe 8000 x 8000 or larger.

Comment: Please edit your question and add all the essential information from comments to the question.

Comment: If you can make a small exemplar data set which could be used for us to test any solutions on, that would be perfect. Only needs to be about 36 files of 200px and any solution can then be scaled up. Otherwise you're going to get a bunch of partial solutions and suggestions instead of complete answers.

Comment: Didn't any of the answers work for you?

Comment: I have managed to successfully use rgb2pct.py to create 1 Band rasters with a colour pallette. I was however surprised that the resulting 1 band image was larger on disk than the 3 band image. I am now looking into creating the tiles. I have to look at what tools would be suitable to use to introduce tiling. I could create a fishnet shapefile and clip the mosaic but maybe there are other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Try 'Rearrange bands' in the Raster conversion within the processing toolbox of QGIS. I think if you select the three bands it will put them together.

You can run this as a batch process.

I am not sure about increasing the size, but maybe that will be a start?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

gdal translate with the flags

```
-b <band> Select an input band band for output. 
-outsize <xsize>[%]|0 <ysize>[%]|0 Set the size of the output file. Outsize is in pixels and lines unless ‘%’ is attached in which case it is as a fraction of the input image size.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know what 6 images you want to combine try these two commands:

```
gdalbuildvrt temporary.vrt file1 file2 file3 file4 file5 file6

rgb2pct.py -of GTiff temporary.vrt single_band_output.tif
```

The target GeoTIFF is rather big and should be created as tiled and perhaps compressed but I do not know if rgb2pct supports creation options. Improve with gdal_translate if needed.